# web3.exceptions.MethodUnavailable: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_chainId does not exist/is not available'}

Tags: ethereum, web3py

In the deployment of intelligent contracts, I use the web3 call web3. Eth. Chain_id method, the error "web3. Exceptions. MethodUnavailable: {' code ': - 32601,' the message: 'The method eth_chainId does not exist/is not available'}”

The error：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\pycharm\WorkTest\TrailChain-main\POC\exp1.py", line 83, in <module>
    notaryAddress, notaryABI, trackerAddress, trackerABI= setup.deploySystemcontracts(trailchainURL)
  File "F:\pycharm\WorkTest\TrailChain-main\POC\setup.py", line 64, in deploySystemcontracts
    'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id,
  File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\web3\eth\eth.py", line 145, in chain_id
    return self._chain_id()
  File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 75, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(
  File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 321, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(
  File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 274, in formatted_response
    raise MethodUnavailable(error)
web3.exceptions.MethodUnavailable: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_chainId does not exist/is not available'}
```

The code:

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(_trailchainURL))
    web3.is_connected()
    #
    #  -- Deploy TrackerSc Contract --
    #
    tracker = web3.eth.contract(abi=abiTracker, bytecode=bytecodeTracker)
    construct_txn = tracker.constructor().build_transaction(
    {
        'from': account_from['address'],
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account_from['address']),
        'chainId': web3.eth.chain_id,
    }
    )

    tx_create = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(construct_txn, account_from['private_key'])
    tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(tx_create.rawTransaction)
    tx_receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
```